# Does BootCamp on OSX El Captain support Windows 10?

Tags: macos, boot-camp, windows-10

I'm considering buying a MacBook Pro next to my Surface Pro 3 for some iOS development.
But I must to be able to run Windows 10 on this machine.
Does bootcamp on El Capitan support Windows 10 or is just Windows 8.1?
If it's supported can anyone provide a guide how to do this from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is supported. Bootcamp in El Capitan will work with Windows versions "8 or later".

See this Apple Support [page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990) for complete documentation on how to do this.